# Error while installing R Commander

Tags: r, while-loop, installation, r-commander

```
library(Rcmdr)
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcmdrMisc’:
 object ‘print.rcorr’ is not exported by 'namespace:Hmisc'
Error: package ‘RcmdrMisc’ could not be loaded
```

Comment: Have you tried installing RcmdrMisc and Hmisc?

Comment: yes... already done that

Answer (score 0):

Or, as a temporary workaround until fixed: install old Version (r-oldrel) of Hmisc: https://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc